# Table with fixed cell width, but auto table width

Tags: css, css-tables

If I have a regular element with `display: table; width: 100%;` the element grows beyond the given width to accommodate for any number of columns. I need this behavior and equal column widths.

All the solutions I've found were either JavaScript (usually jQuery) or said to use `table-layout: fixed` which needs a fixed width for the table (eg, 100%) but the table contains a lot of data and not even 1000px can accommodate that much information.

How can I reproduce this behavior with CSS?

Comment: if your table can't be printed in < 1000px, you may want to rethink your logic and design...

Comment: No, this is scientific information, this is the design. There can be anywhere between one and two hundred columns of data and they all need to be in the same table.

Comment: What should the equal width be?

Comment: If you want an equal width that is the minimum width to accommodate any cell content (without line wrapping), which is my best guess of what the question means, then you obviously need (simple) JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
Something like this then?
http://jsfiddle.net/Jax5z/1/

---

Depending on browser support you require, and what info is being displayed, you can cut off the text within the table cells if they are too long, which still allows the table to stretch and fill the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jax5z/

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    cursor: crosshair;
    background: #eee;
}

td {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, it's obvious you started writing before I added my comment to the question. But there are hundreds of columns. I need to support scrolling.

Comment: Like that, but the columns should have equal widths.

Comment: You can set widths on the <td> elements, but table cells will always expand if their content is larger than the width you've set. No way around that without doing what I had originally.